# Apache Avro C Installation

Tags: c, linux, gcc, avro

I am working on a project and I am using Apache Avro. I have downloaded Apache Avro for C and I followed the instructions provided in order to install it on my system (Ubuntu Linux v14.04). After the installation, I have some header files under the `/include` directory and some libraries under `/lib` directory. All of those are the ones that were installed from Apache Avro.

At this point, I have created my C source files which are as follows:

1) socket_client.h :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include "avro.h"
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#ifndef SOCKET_CLIENT_H_
#define SOCKET_CLIENT_H_

void init_schema(void);

int client_execution_connect(char* ip_addr, int port, char* type);

#endif /* SOCKET_CLIENT_H_ */
```

2) socket_client.c :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "socket_client.h"

avro_schema_t bigpeer_schema;
void init_schema(void)
{
    if( avro_schema_from_json_literal(BIG_PEER_SCHEMA, &bigpeer_schema) )
    {
        printf("Unable to parse big_peer schema");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
int client_execution_connect(char* ip_addr, int port, char* type)
{
    ...
}
```

and a test main file. Also, I have created the following makefile to compile my code:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
LDFLAGS=
SOURCES=test_main.c socket_client.c
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.c=.o)
EXECUTABLE=avro_test
INC_PATH=/include/avro/

INC=-I/include
LIB=-L/lib

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIB) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

.c.o:
    $(CC) $(INC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf *.o avro_test
```

But, when I try to make my application, I get the following:

```
nick@rethimno:~/Downloads/AvroClient$ make
gcc -I/include -c -Wall test_main.c -o test_main.o
test_main.c: In function ‘main’:
test_main.c:22:6: warning: unused variable ‘port’ [-Wunused-variable]
  int port = atoi(argv[2]);
      ^
test_main.c:15:8: warning: unused variable ‘type’ [-Wunused-variable]
   char* type = "db_node";
        ^
gcc -I/include -c -Wall socket_client.c -o socket_client.o
gcc  -L/lib test_main.o socket_client.o -o avro_test
socket_client.o: In function `init_schema':
socket_client.c:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `avro_schema_from_json_length'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [avro_test] Error 1
```

What am I doing wrong? I am not quite certain if the libraries of Apache Avro are loaded properly.

Thank you,
Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are including the Avro headers, but you aren't linking your final executable against the Avro libraries. Assuming you have `libavro.so` or `libavro.a` in the `lib` directory (where `*.so` is a shared library, and `*.a` is a static library), you will want to change this line of your Makefile:

`LDFLAGS=-lavro`

Note that, if the library binary is called something other than `libavro.so` or `libavro.a`, you'll need to change the `-lavro` value to match. Also note that certain packages can contain more than one shared library you will need to link against. I am not familiar enough with Apache Avro to say whether or not this is the case; you will mostly just need to look and see what is inside your `lib` directory.

You can more information about linking to libraries in the [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I agree with your answer and I try to link the libraries needed in the makefile command `gcc -L/lib test_main.o socket_client.o -o avro_test`. All of the Avro libraries (static and shared) are located in the `/lib` folder. I must be doing something wrong though.

Comment: `-L...` just tells GCC where to *look for libraries*, it doesn't actually tell it to link against any of them. You need `-L/lib` *as well as* `-lavro` or whatever.

Comment: Actually, this worked. The problem was that I did not use `-lavro` and therefore the linking failed. Thank you very much for your help.