# How to include Apache Avro C header files?

Tags: c, makefile, avro

I am trying to use Apache Avro C in a program to better understand how it works. I downloaded Apache Avro for C and installed it on my system (CentOS 7.8.2003). I'm trying to run a copy of the example program provided in the [Avro documentation](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/api/c/index.html#_examples).

```
// avro_test.c
#include <avro.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

...
```

My directory structure looks like this:

```
avro_test.c
Makefile
avro-c-1.10.0
  - build
    - src
      - libavro.a
      - libavro.so
  - src
    - avro.h
    - avro
      - // Other header files referenced in avro.h
```

My Makefile is similar to the one provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24315968/apache-avro-c-installation) and is listed below:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
LDFLAGS=-lavro
SOURCES=avro_test.c
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.c=.o)
EXECUTABLE=avro_test
INC_PATH=/avro-c-1.10.0/src/

INC=-I/avro-c-1.10.0/src/ -I/avro-c-1.10.0/src/avro
LIB=-L/avro-c-1.10.0/build/src

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
        $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIB) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

.c.o:
        $(CC) $(INC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
clean:
        rm -rf *.o avro_test
```

When I run `make` from the outermost directory, I receive the following error:

```
gcc -I/avro-c-1.10.0/src/ -I/avro-c-1.10.0/src/avro -c -Wall avro_test.c -o avro_test.o
avro_test.c:18:18: fatal error: avro.h: No such file or directory
#include <avro.h>
                 ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [avro_test.o] Error 1
```

I've also tried replacing `<avro.h>` with `"avro.h`", but the same error appeared.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it was a silly mistake on my part. In the Makefile, I changed the paths from absolute paths to relative paths (`INC_PATH=/avro-c-1.10.0/src/` became `INC_PATH=./avro-c-1.10.0/src/`). Once I changed all the paths the issue disappeared.